# Bootstrap is not working in laravel 5.4

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5.4

I am facing a very weird problem in my laravel 5.4 application. I am using webpack-mix for compiling my assets. In webpack I have required bootstrap-saas for bootstrap js. Laravel default app.js file is in my master blade.
I added bootstrap in my app.js file.

I want to add different javascript files for different views alog with the app.js. so i have created an import section in my master blade where I can import my view related javascript and CSS files.

Here is my code -

in my app.blade.js

```
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
@yield('imports')
```

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
$(document).ready(function() {});
```

custom.js

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#mymodal').modal('show);
 });
```

custom.blade.php

```
@section('imports')
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ mix('/js/custom.js') }}"> </script>
@endsection
```

its giving me *javascript modal is not a function* error. If i do require bootstrap in my custom file then modal is working fine but javascript gets loaded twice and other functionalities like accordion and all not working.
If i call that modal function from my app.js its working fine.
can you please tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: The default `./bootstrap` is not the Bootstrap Framework javascript file and you should include your imports after app.js

Comment: Shouldn't `@yield('imports')` be AFTER app.js (where bootstrap is imported)

Comment: Sorry. It was my mistake. I am already importing the custom js after app.js file. I have updated my question.

Comment: @DestinatioN /.bootstrap required *bootstrap-saas* package which having the bootstrap js and all.